# Does array assignment create a new reference

Tags: javascript

I am running into the following situation. I am initializing an array, and assigning it to an object's property.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var obj = { 'numbers': arr };
```

I understand that I passed a reference to my array `arr` to my object `obj`. So I can do the following:

```
arr.push(6);
console.log(obj);
```

will display the following, as expected:

```
{ numbers: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }
```

Now for the unexpected part. The value of `arr` changes, through an external event, and I want the value of `obj.numbers` to change at the same time. But it does not:

```
arr = [0,0,0,0,0];
console.log(arr);
console.log(obj);
arr --> [0,0,0,0,0]
obj --> { numbers: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }
```

So the value of my `arr` variable changed, but not the `numbers` property in my `obj` variable.

So, my only explanation is, that as soon as you perform an assignment to an array, you break the old reference and create a new reference. Is that so?

And how would I assign my new values `[0,0,0,0,0]` to my `arr` variable and the `obj.numbers` (at the same time)?

Comment: By `obj = {numbers: arr} ` you are saying "I want my obj property `numbers` to be equal to what is there named `arr` right now" which happens to be a ref to array. If you want `obj.numbers` to always be what is there in variable `arr` you could define custom getter `obj = { get numbers() { return arr} }`. Now you could just say `arr = "blah"` and `obj.numbers` will return whatever `arr` holds in the moment of accessing the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an assignment with `=` creates a new reference and gets rid of the old one. To get around this:

```js
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var obj = { 'numbers': arr };
  console.log(arr === obj.numbers); // -> true

  arr.length = 0;
  var newArr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  arr.push(...newArr);
  console.log(arr === obj.numbers); // -> true
  console.log(arr); // -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Setting length equal to 0 clears the array. When you push items into an array, it doesn't create a new array, so you'll see both `arr` and `obj` change.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) as well for a new array.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5],
    object = { numbers: array },
    newArray = [41, 42, 43];

[].splice.apply(array, [0, array.length].concat(newArray));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the exact documentation on this, but after some experimentation, I concluded that an assignment indeed creates a new reference.

This is the way I ended up solving this.

```
arr.splice(0);
[0,0,0,0,0].map(el => arr.push(el);
```

This gives me the following expected result.

```
console.log(arr);
console.log(obj);
arr --> [0,0,0,0,0]
obj --> { numbers: [0,0,0,0,0] }
```

By the way, the same is true for objects, which would be logical, since arrays are a type of object.

Comment: `arr.slice(0);` this doesn't make sense w/o assignment. `slice` creates *new*  array keeping original array intact. So since you do not store the result basically this operation only heats your cpu. Then `[0,0,0,0,0].map(el => arr.push(el))` again `map` semantically should be used to create new array w/ "mapped" items. Since you have no assignment you better use `forEach`.

Comment: I meant to use splice

Answer (score 0):

It works right. Variable is a place where you save a reference. You save in `arr` another reference.

You can update first array using this code.

```
arr.length = 0;
arr.push(...[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
```

`slice` method won't help you because it return new copy of array.

Comment: You're pushing an array into `arr`, so `arr` now looks like `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`. This is not what the question wanted.